# "Unexpected token this" from JS class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error: unexpected token this. I have a class that's going to store a lot of properties. One of the properties, rawData, will be a multi-dimensional array that comes from a CSV. One of the methods will check the 1st array (i.e. zeroth) to see if it's numbers or labels. **I will not be able to pass the CSV data at the time of object creation, it must be set later.** I've simplified my code here to make it easier to read.

```
//DropProperties Class
class Droperties{
    rawData;

    constructor(){

    }

    isFirstRowLabel(this.rawData){
        if(this.rawData[0].some(isNaN)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


var droperties = new Droperties();
droperties.rawData = [
    ['Orks', 'Imperial Gaurd', 'Space Marines', 'Chaos Daemons', 'Tyranids', 'Elda'],
    [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];
console.log(droperties.isFirstRowLabel);
```

Can someone shed some light on how to approach this issue?

Comment: It's just `isFirstRowLabel()` – you can't and don't need to pass class properties as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As JJJ said, I didn't need to pass class properties as parameters. Also, I appeared to be missing the empty parens on the `console.log(droperties.isFirstRowLabel);`

The following works:

```
//DropProperties Class
class Droperties{
    rawData;

    constructor(){

    }

    isFirstRowLabel(){
        if(!this.rawData[0].some(isNaN)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


var droperties = new Droperties();
droperties.rawData = [
    ['Orks', 'Imperial Gaurd', 'Space Marines', 'Chaos Daemons', 'Tyranids', 'Elda'],
    [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];
console.log(droperties.isFirstRowLabel());
```